# Is it necessary use `.primary()` method after `.increment()` method?

Tags: knex.js

I read `knex.js` docs and find there is a little difference between some examples.

https://knexjs.org/#Schema-createTable use `table.increment()`

https://knexjs.org/#Schema-hasTable use `table.increment().primary()`

Are they equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. `.increment` (sadly) creates a primary key by default.